# Can I receive SAML 2.0 message in ASP.NET without WIF?

Tags: asp.net, saml

We are planning to receive a SAML assertion from another website into ours (ASP.NET). No one here has ever worked with SAML. We simply need to verify the signed assertion, decrypt the token containing a user id and if we can verify it, log them into our site (authenticate/authorize). We are using Forms Authentication for all other authentication. I would like to avoid installing WIF if possible because my understanding is we'd have to install the runtime on all the developers machines and servers. Our machines are locked down by policy such that it would be a lot of paper work to get it installed. Are there alternatives to WIF and are they realistic to use in an enterprise environment? If so, can someone point me in the right direction, a good tutorial, video, book or anything with examples would be helpful? I looked at some third party components but I'd have the same issue as with WIF on our servers (not to mention dealing with procurement).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is this internal or an external facing application? You may want to checkout PingOne.com Application Provider Services (APS) [Note: I work for Ping]. PingOne handles all the SAML protocol stuff for you and provides self-service capabilities, reporting, etc. No need to install WIF... just a few lines of .NET code (or whatever) to integrate with the RESTful service that PingOne provides.

HTH - Ian

Comment: The other website is part of our company. Clients will be entering from thier site and directed to ours. Their site is Java based and we are .NET. We share no services or dbs so that is why we decided on SAML.